# Transfer data to gridview columns

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devextreme

I have a main grid and one of the columns is editbutton. When I click the edit button inside the this grid,open an another form. After double click the this form, it is closed and I move the values to the my main grid. But so far, I t can transfer data but not shown inside the main grid. **I also "add new row event" enable which I move values to the inside that.
(I am also check that fieldname, name of the gridview properties are correct but not working)

```
//edit button doubleclcik event here 

private void btnStokSec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string Id = OpenAnaotherForm();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
   {
      int _Id = Convert.ToInt32(Id);
      Stoklar stoklar = bll_stk.GetirById(_stokId)[0];
      string f4 = stoklar.Birim.ToString();
      this.gridView1.AddNewRow();
      MessageBox.Show(f7.ToString()); //I am able to get data correctly here
      this.gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue(Birim, f4);// but not here
      ............
      ...........
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more code?  Code from both forms?  You say the f7 variable has data, but I don't see where that is getting set.

You could also look at adding a public method to the underlying form that the pop up form could call and pass a value.